# Java: Getting object from bound-method-reference

Tags: java, events, observer-pattern, method-reference

## TL;DR

Is there some way to get `my_object` from within a function `do_something` that is called with a method-reference:

```
other_object.do_something(my_object::some_method);
```

## Full Story...

**Background**: I'm making a system wherein modules communicate by passing events to one another.  Each module consumes events via one or more methods of the form `<EventType> void eat_event(EventType ev)`.  (There may be different ways to eat an event, and a given module may be able to eat different types of events using different methods).  Each module maintains a list of consumers, and sends events to them.  Modules are connected via the add_listener method:

```
class Module{
    ...
    public <EventType> void add_listener(Consumer<EventType> consumer){
        this.listeners.add(consumer);
    }
}
```

In the initialization code, I binds modules together like:

```
module_1.add_listener(module_2::eat_event);
```

**Now, the question**:
Is there some way to extract the object (in this case `module_2`) that the method reference `module_2::eat_event` belongs to?  Suppose, for some reason, I want `module_1` to maintain a table of all modules it sends events to.  Currently, I have to change the add_listener definition to:

```
public <EventType> void add_listener(Module dest_module, Consumer<EventType> consumer){...}
```

And bind with:

```
module_1.add_listener(module_2, module_2::eat_event);
```

Which looks redundant when you're binding everything together, and opens up room for programming errors, since you might accidentally specify a method that does not belong to the destination module.

**The real problem**: I simplified the problem for the sake of the question, but the real problem is that I'm building an intermediate "router" class that may want to buffer the outputs of `module_1` before feeding them to `module_2`.  The problem is that when I specify connectivity via the router class, I need to know the dependency structure between modules, which is lost when you just pass in a source module and a method reference for the destination module.

## Conclusions so far

(Updated 15:30 29 Dec 2015)
No, as far as I can see there is no way to do that.

But also, I found I didn't need to do this for my program... So while there may be some reasons you want to do this, mine wasn't one of them.

Comment: How are you getting hold of module_2::eat_event to be added as one of the listeners in module_1?

Comment: The class that binds together all the modules contains references to all modules.  So it's just `this.module_1.add_listener(this.module_2::eat_event);`

Comment: You have reference to all modules and you want to maintain a table of all modules that it sends events to , in that case whenever you call add_listener and you know what module that eat_event ( I assume that its a class )  belongs to : add to a hashmap : map_of_listeners.put( module, eat_event) - this is inside add_listener. I mean first check if its there in the map otherwise add it to map, then while getting all listeners later, just iterate through values of that map.

Comment: No what I want to maintain in the example is not "a table of listeners" but "a table of the module that each listener belongs to".  So I want to get the object to which "eat_event" belongs.  I'm not sure if this is possible without the redundant code mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am assuming you have access to the eat_event class ( if I amnot wrong ) but you don't have access to the class that owns eat_event listener class. That's the problem. I know using Java reflection you might be able to achieve it, but I think its overkill. Without specifying what module yourself that the eat_event belongs to I am not sure if this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a method having a parameter of type `Consumer<EventType>`, there is no guaranty that the implementation of the `Consumer` is a method reference nor that, if it is implemented via a method reference, it has captured an object of a particular type. If you want to declare a particular dependency between the two arguments, you may do it the other way round:

```
public <M extends Module, E> void add_listener(M dest_module, BiConsumer<M,E> listener){
    ...
}
```

Since the method is expected to remember the association between the `dest_module` and the `listener`, there should be no problem supplying the `dest_module` as first argument to the `accept` method of the `listener`.

In this constellation, the listener doesn’t need to capture the module instance at all. A typical use case, derived from your example, would be like:

```
module_1.add_listener(module_2, TypeOfModule2::eat_event);
```

Here, the method reference doesn’t capture a module instance and the listener notification implementation will eventually invoke the `eat_event` method on the instance provided at registration time. So you have no redundancy here and no chance of mixing up module instances.

However, as said, there is no guaranty about how a caller of `add_listener` implements the listener interface. You can’t prevent all possibilities of counteracting implementations. You can only try to make intentional implementations easy and counteracting stuff harder to implement.